# How can I use LEAD LAG-like functions on multiple columns simultaneously

Tags: window-functions

Suppose I have the following table:

```
start_data | end_date
----------------------
t1         | Null
Null       | t2
t3         | Null
Null       | t4
t5         | Null
```

The output should be like this:

```
start_data | end_date
----------------------
t1         | t2
t3         | t4
t5         | Null
```

**notes:**

- the type of *ti* is date
- *ti < ti+1* holds true for all values.

*pseudo code:*
 for every record i
    xi <--- start_date
    yi <--- end_date
    zi <---- min(yi) && xi>yi
    (xi,zi) should be the output for this record i

Is it solvable using native SQL?

Comment: Your dataset have no any ordering info. So "first"-"last"-"previous"-"next" terms not exists. So the task is unsolvable.

Comment: @Akina Well I guess one could order by `coalesce(start_data, end_date)` or the equivalent in the OP's DBMS of choice, which he sadly failed to mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess one could order by `coalesce(start_data, end_date)`

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT COALESCE(start_data, end_date) dt, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COALESCE(start_data, end_date)) rn
FROM datatable
)
SELECT MIN(dt) start_data, MAX(dt) end_date
FROM cte
GROUP BY ROUND((rn-1)/2)
```

This query is a model. The final text is dependent by DBMS.

Maybe you will need to replace MIN/MAX with `CASE WHEN rn%2 = [0|1]`